# How do you configure Solr 8.1.1 for TLS / SSL including replication with a PFX (PKCS12) certificate?

Tags: solr

I started off following [this post](https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/08/20/using-the-pkcs12-pfx-format-for-solr-ssl-security/) to setup TLS with a certificate with the PFX extension. An issue was revealed while trying to setup Solr replication; Wireshark showed **Certificate Unknown** when the secondary server made requests to the primary. This lead me down the path that Solr SSL/TLS needs to be configured.

Initial setup:

- Solr running over http/8983
- Certificate configured in IIS and added to `Cert:\LocalMachine\My`
- Rewrite rule in IIS to transfer traffic from `https://scms.tst.sxp.local` to `http://127.0.0.1/solr`

Modified setup:

- Updated rewrite rule to use `https://127.0.0.1/solr` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/solr`
- Updated `solr.in.cmd`

```plain
set SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/wildcard.sxp.local.pfx
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=OriginalSecret123
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/wildcard.sxp.local.pfx
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=OriginalSecret123
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12
```

The certificate was provided by our Security Team so we could add it to IIS and our load balancer. Once solr starts I see this error message:

> Java java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Apparently changing from jks to pkcs12 has this undesired affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, it turns out that the original version of Java 8 (`jdk8u222-b10-jre`) used does not have proper support for PKCS12.

Steps to fix:

- Download a newer version of Java

  - In my case I jumped up to Java 14 but you could get by with 12 (or maybe 11 (I'm not sure, just guessing))
- Export the certificate with the private key using a different password (`secret`) and specifying TripleDES instead of AES256

  - Using TripleDES was revealed as an issue where the password was invalid

[image]